# The object invoked has disconnected from its clients - VBA- SQL Query

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I wrote a invoice tool in Excel/VBA.

I'm getting a error mesage when I try to run the code (in Excel) below and I don't know why?

Error mesage: The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.

usfOKNAR01.txtfakt4.Value is a combobox from which I take the ID of the invoice.

----VBA code to run a query from Access Data base.

```
Public Sub faktury2()
SQL = ""
SQL = Array("SELECT * FROM [pokaz_Raty] WHERE ID = " & usfOKNAR01.txtfakt4.Value & ";", _
"SELECT DISTINCT(tbINCOME.[Faktura_ID]), tbRATY.[Faktura_ID] FROM tbRATY INNER JOIN tbINCOME ON tbRATY.[Faktura_ID] = tbINCOME.Identyfikator;")
For i = 0 To 1
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open SQL(i), db, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly 'here the error mesage jumps.
GoTo dalej2
Next i
Exit Sub
dalej2:
Select Case i
Case 0
With usfOKNAR01.MultiPage1.Pages(9).lb4
    .Clear
    .ColumnCount = rs.Fields.Count
    'NAGLOWKI
    w = 0
    For z = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
    .AddItem
    .List(w, z) = rs.Fields(z).Name
    Next z
                w = 1
                        Do
                        .AddItem
                        For z = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
                            If IsNull(rs.Fields(z)) = True Or rs.Fields(z).Value = 0 Then
                            .List(w, z) = "Brak danych!"
                            Else
                            .List(w, z) = rs.Fields(z).Value
                            End If
                Next z
                w = w + 1
                rs.MoveNext
                Loop Until rs.EOF
    End With
Case 1
With usfOKNAR01.txtfakt4
        .ColumnCount = rs.Fields.Count
        .Clear
        w = 0
        rs.MoveFirst
            Do
                If IsNull(rs.Fields(0)) Then
                .AddItem ""
                Else
                .AddItem
                .List(w, 0) = rs.Fields(1).Value
                .List(w, 1) = rs.Fields(0).Value
                End If
            rs.MoveNext
            w = w + 1
            Loop Until rs.EOF
End With
End Select
```

In Access I have a query called pokaz_Raty

SQL code looks like this:

```
SELECT tbRATY.Faktura_ID AS ID, tbKLIENT.KLIENT AS KLIENT, tbINCOME.Faktura_ID AS [NR-FAKT], tbINCOME.kwota_brutto AS [KWOTA BRUTTO], tbRATY.Kwota AS WPŁACONO, [tbINCOME].[kwota_brutto]-[tbRATY].[Narastajaco] AS [DO ZAPŁATY], tbRATY.Data
FROM tbKLIENT INNER JOIN (tbINCOME INNER JOIN (SELECT *, (SELECT Sum(KWOTA)  FROM tbRATY t WHERE t.Faktura_ID=tbRATY.Faktura_ID AND t.Identyfikator<=tbRATY.Identyfikator )As Narastajaco FROM tbRATY)  AS tbRATY ON tbINCOME.Identyfikator = tbRATY.Faktura_ID) ON tbKLIENT.Identyfikator = tbINCOME.klient
ORDER BY tbRATY.Data;
```

Can somebothy look at it ant help me with my issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an error because you have not assigned a value to sql0. Actually I can't figure out why you have the For i = 0 To 1 loop and why you have the Array(Select...).

Try this

```
Public Sub faktury2()

Dim SQL as String

SQL="SELECT tbRATY.Faktura_ID AS ID, tbKLIENT.KLIENT AS KLIENT, tbINCOME.Faktura_ID AS [NR-FAKT]," 
SQL=SQL & " tbINCOME.kwota_brutto AS [KWOTA BRUTTO], tbRATY.Kwota AS WPLACONO," 
SQL=SQL & " [tbINCOME].[kwota_brutto]-[tbRATY].[Narastajaco] AS [DO ZAPLATY], tbRATY.Data"
SQL=SQL & " FROM tbKLIENT INNER JOIN (tbINCOME INNER JOIN" 
SQL=SQL & " (SELECT *, (SELECT Sum(KWOTA)  FROM tbRATY t" 
SQL=SQL & " WHERE t.Faktura_ID=tbRATY.Faktura_ID "
SQL=SQL & " AND t.Identyfikator<=tbRATY.Identyfikator )As Narastajaco FROM tbRATY)  AS tbRATY"
SQL=SQL & " ON tbINCOME.Identyfikator = tbRATY.Faktura_ID) ON tbKLIENT.Identyfikator = tbINCOME.klient"
SQL=SQL & " ORDER BY tbRATY.Data"

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open SQL, db, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

If rs.EOF AND rs.BOF = FALSE then

    GoTo dalej2

End if
Exit Sub
dalej2:
Select Case i
Case 0
With usfOKNAR01.MultiPage1.Pages(9).lb4
    .Clear
    .ColumnCount = rs.Fields.Count
    'NAGLOWKI
    w = 0
    For z = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
    .AddItem
    .List(w, z) = rs.Fields(z).Name
    Next z
                w = 1
                        Do
                        .AddItem
                        For z = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
                            If IsNull(rs.Fields(z)) = True Or rs.Fields(z).Value = 0 Then
                            .List(w, z) = "Brak danych!"
                            Else
                            .List(w, z) = rs.Fields(z).Value
                            End If
                Next z
                w = w + 1
                rs.MoveNext
                Loop Until rs.EOF
    End With
Case 1
With usfOKNAR01.txtfakt4
        .ColumnCount = rs.Fields.Count
        .Clear
        w = 0
        rs.MoveFirst
            Do
                If IsNull(rs.Fields(0)) Then
                .AddItem ""
                Else
                .AddItem
                .List(w, 0) = rs.Fields(1).Value
                .List(w, 1) = rs.Fields(0).Value
                End If
            rs.MoveNext
            w = w + 1
            Loop Until rs.EOF
End With
End Select 

End Sub
```

I have not tested our thoroughly checked the sql. Just copied what you said was working in access and split it into multi lines to make it easier to read.